# Emacs is not running processes as arm process on m1 mac, rather it seems to x86 emulation? Can I make everything native?

Tags: osx, process

My emacs seems to be spawning processes using x86 emuation, which then breaks certain python packages since binary modules that I install outside of emacs are for x86.  A workaround I found was to create a virtualenv from with emacs since (I suspect) this then downloads x86 wheels. Also this behaviour only occurs if I start emacs with spotlight or `open -a Emacs` - so another workaround is to **run emacs from a terminal window**. ([This stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68199148/application-reports-different-architecture-depending-on-launch-method) discusses similar for someone trying to wrap their project with a mac application.)

As a example if I run `(shell-command-to-string "uname -a")` it returns a different value from in a shell. I would prefer to not deal with any emulation or virtualenvs... but I'm sort of running out of justifiable energy debugging (see [rambly post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76407128/why-is-platform-processor-returning-the-wrong-value-when-python-is-run-from-my?noredirect=1#comment134733337_76407128)).

What's the state of play for emacs on M1? I was suspicious that it might be doing it's own "emulation"... but I'm not so sure now. Can I get it to spawn processes natively.

## To reproduce

1. Start emacs
2. Run `(shell-command-to-string "uname -a")` in emacs
3. Run `uname -a` in a separate terminal
4. The cpu architecture does not match

## Debugging

This problem only seems to occur if I start emacs from spotlight.

This question looks like it might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68199148/application-reports-different-architecture-depending-on-launch-method

Answer (score 1):

Emacs runs perfectly fine natively on Apple Silicon. With Homebrew, I just `brew install --cask emacs` and it pulls in [Emacs for macOS](https://emacsformacos.com/), installs it in `/Applications`, and adds a symlink to `emacs`. If I remember I'll re-symlink the `bin/` and `libexec/` directories in the app bundle to point to the arm version (neither the installer nor the Homebrew formula do this for some reason.) I don't run Rosetta at all, so the universal binary does the right thing. If you're using Emacs for macOS too, you may have to tweak symlinks yourself, namely point any `emacs` symlink to `Emacs-arm64-11` instead of the universal binary `Emacs`. You can also force the architecture of any universal binary on macOS with the `arch` command, e.g. `arch -arm64 emacs`.

Comment: Thanks... the problem is that it seems (for example when I am using org-babel) to be spawning processes running with x86 emulation rather than using arm.

Comment: Yeah, I got that from your question. The point is, ensure that you're running a native Emacs (or the arm64 arch in a universal binary). Use the `arch` command, or the `ARCHPREFERENCE` environment variable.

Comment: Hmm... I'm having a look around `/Applicaiton/Emacs` to work out what might be different. I'm suspicious of the `launch.rs` file.

Comment: I'm running a native emacs I think (the "Kind" in activity monitor is Apple) and the binary name is Emacs-arm64-11. I just experimented with emacs -q and then discovered that the problem does not occur if I spawn arch from a terminal rather than spotlight (I reran with my full config)

Comment: The `launch.rs` file is the Rust code for the app launcher ie `Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs`.

Comment: Okay... I'm pretty sure that this is the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68199148/application-reports-different-architecture-depending-on-launch-method (it describes similar behaviour: the problem occurs only when started as an application, shell processes run under rosetta). Unfortunately, there are no fixes in the question. I've added a bounty to the question - we'll see if that gives us an answer.